# What RSS feeds other than "recent" questions are available?

Tags: support, status-completed

Whenever there is a lot of activity on editing, re-tagging or other clean-up efforts my RSS feed for recent activites gets cluttered with old posts.

How do I subscribe to the "newest question" feed? What other feeds are available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per default only a link to the recent question feed is diplayed on the site's main page. However in case we would like to subscribe to another feed the following are available:

- https://german.stackexchange.com/feeds/ for "**Recent** Questions" (default)
- https://german.stackexchange.com/feeds/newest for "**Newest** Questions"
- https://german.stackexchange.com/feeds/featured for "**Featured** Questions"
- http://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/499 for "Starred Questions in **Chat**"
- https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/ for "**Recent Meta** Questions"
- https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/newest for "**Newest Meta** Questions"
- https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag/`<tag>` for Questions **tagged** with `<tag>`
- https://german.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/`<id-number>` for Activites of **user** `<id-number>`